# php pdo select query with where condition and order by clause

Tags: php, mysql, pdo

I need to select youtube source from my database.

i create my code in php pdo.

for that i put condition like this...

but this is not working and even not showing any error or also not display video.

when I remove where condition from below select query its working properly....

plz suggest how to put this condition in select query using php pdo prepared statements.

thanks...

**below is my code to select..**

```
<?php
$youtubesource = "youtubesource <>  ''";
$youtube = $database->getRows("SELECT youtubesource FROM news where youtubesource = :youtubesource ORDER BY id DESC LIMIT 0,1",array(':youtubesource'=>$youtubesource));                        
?>
```

**below is my getrows function**

```
 public function getRows($query, $params=array()){
            try{ 
                $stmt = $this->datab->prepare($query); 
                $stmt->execute($params);
                return $stmt->fetchAll();       
                }catch(PDOException $e){
                throw new Exception($e->getMessage());
            }       
        }
```

Comment: It looks like you have a bad parameter array - is that the real value for `$youtubesource`?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If i analyze your query decently, this is what I see:

```
SELECT youtubesource 
FROM news 
WHERE youtubesource = :youtubesource     
ORDER BY id DESC 
LIMIT 0,1
```

With `:youtubesource` being `youtubesource <>  ''`, the final query will be:

```
SELECT youtubesource 
FROM news 
WHERE youtubesource = 'youtubesource <> '''   
ORDER BY id DESC
LIMIT 0,1
```

What does `youtubesource <>  ''` suggest is that you are trying to get all rows which have not empty youtubesource field.

In that case, your code might look like this:

```
$youtube = $database->getRows("SELECT youtubesource FROM news where youtubesource <> '' AND youtubesource is not null ORDER BY id DESC LIMIT 0,1");
```

Comment: thanks for help . your query is working properly but ..i need to ask you this query with where condition is in php pdo prepared query .. my mean is passing where condition is secured from mysql injection...bcoz i passed where condition using array

Comment: You array is useless since you just want to check if the value is empty or not. Prepared statement are useful in case you want to check for dynamic values in where clauses. In this case, this is not dynamic, it's checking for not null which does not depend on any external parameter.

Answer (score 0):

Do you need the : in the array parameter you are sending through to the function?

```
$youtube = $database->getRows("SELECT youtubesource FROM news where youtubesource = :youtubesource ORDER BY id DESC LIMIT 0,1",array('youtubesource'=>$youtubesource));
```

Also, is this right: $youtubesource = "youtubesource <>  ''";
As wouldn't this be
SELECT youtubesource FROM news where youtubesource = `youtubesource <>  ''` ORDER BY id DESC LIMIT
or something like that

Comment: this query is working properly in mysql but i convbert my code in pdo prepared statements ang in pdo this is not working..plz suggest how to pass above condition in my query.  i am inserting youtubesource in my database is like //www.youtube.com/embed/bVl3om0-GFE this...  this is embed src of youtube video

Comment: yes my condition $youtubesource = "youtubesource <> ''";  is exact and also working with mysql properly